# Where should we need to convert images from rgb to greyscal in image classification

Tags: neural-network, dataset, conv-neural-network, dynamics-al

I am working with an plant disease image classifiaction, is it necessary to convert the dataset to greyscal

Comment: If most of the test images are not grayscale, I see no reason to convert images to grayscale.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.